# using directive is unnecessary visual studio - random class

Tags: c#

I want to use Random class but I got this error message:

```
using directive is unnecessary visual studio
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Random; //I got this error at this line

namespace Mikrotik
{
....
```

Answer (score 3):

### Quick-fix:

You only need `using System;` - inside your code you can use `Random` directly.

### Background:

Please read the documentation for C#'s `using` directive: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

I think you're imagining that `using` works like how `import` works in Java where you have to name each type you want to bring into scope or use `.*` to bring all types into scope. Instead, C#'s `using` only imports namespaces, making it roughly equivalent to Java's `import` being used exclusively with the `.*` syntax.

You're getting the error because there is no namespace `System.Random`, instead it's a type-name; so you just need `using System;` - in your code you can use `Random` as-is.

For pendantry: C#'s `using` directive has 3 different modes:

1. `using namespace;` - brings into scope all types in the specified namespace
2. `using Alias = namespace.TypeName;` - brings into scope a single type, but with an alias. The alias can match the original name.
3. `using static namespace.TypeName;` - brings only the static members of the specified type into scope.

Not to be confused with C#s `using() {}` statement, which is completely unrelated to importing types and namespaces.

Comment: @AluanHaddad `using static` doesn't bring a type's name into scope, only its static members. As `System.Random` doesn't have static members it's not applicable for the OP.

Comment: The .Net documentation always tells you which name space you should use. I normally enter this scear string in Google: C# Random (or the class I like to use)and this never fails to find the correct pages right a way.